# pinyin input candidate window doesn't show up

Tags: keyboard, text-input

I'm using MacOS Mojave's `Pinyin - Simplified` to type Chinese characters. It always worked well but recently it has refused to show candidate characters. A similar problem was reported [on Apple's forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7721763) but no useful answer. Any suggestions?

[image]

Actually, I restarted my computer and things went back to normal.

But anyone has any idea how to prevent this in future?

Comment: What is your macos version?  The Apple forum stuff is from years ago.   Add a screen shot of what you see when you type “wo” in Pages.

Comment: Just added the image

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working again.  Perhaps restart your computer more often?

Comment: Thanks. To be honest I hate restarting. It's 21st century yet we still have to restart computers???

Comment: Understood, but it is definitely the first thing to try when you encounter a problem.